# How to build boost to have boost_python-vcxx-mt-gd-1_xx.lib in among the libs

Tags: windows, visual-studio, boost-python

I'm trying to build boost on Windows machine. But after build got
cannot open file 'boost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib error. I looked for it in stage/lib dir and there is no python lib. So is there any doc or something that can help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to the docs that helped me with my boost building woes:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html
http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

Try to build 'boost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib' separately with boost.build. The resources should be enough to get you going.